# Overcomming selection by label warning

Tags: pandas

I have the following `df`:

```
       col1   col2
   A    2       3
   B    4       5 
   E    6       7
```

I would like to generate a `new_df` looking for the lines of my interest using the selection by label `.loc` attribute.
In order to do so what I did was:

```
new_df= df.loc[['A','B','C','D','E'],:]
```

Using version pandas 0.19 I obtained the following output:

```
       col1   col2
   A    2       3
   B    4       5 
   E    6       7
   C   Nan     Nan
   D   Nan     Nan
```

Outputting `Nan` values for those index values that did not appear in the `df` .

Now I have updated pandas to 0.23 and now the following  `FutureWarning` appears:

```
FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

In order to follow pandas advice, I changed the the line of code according to pandas recommendation :

```
new_df=df.loc[df.index.intersection(['A','B','C','D','E'])]
```

However the issue now is that the output is:

```
       col1   col2
   A    2       3
   B    4       5 
   E    6       7
```

where I would like the index values that do not exist in the `df` to appear in the `new_df`.

I have 2 questions then:

- How can I overcome this issue to obtain the desired output adhering to pandas recommendations and eliminating the `FutureWarning`?
- Does `FutureWarning` means that from one day to another a `KeyError` error will arise, or that you would have to upgrade pandas version for the error to arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for avoid error:

```
new_df= df.reindex(['A','B','C','D','E'])
print (new_df)
   col1  col2
A   2.0   3.0
B   4.0   5.0
C   NaN   NaN
D   NaN   NaN
E   6.0   7.0
```

> Does FutureWarning means that from one day to another a KeyError error will arise, or that you would have to upgrade pandas version for the error to arise?

Need to upgrade pandas to future version for raise error.